# Simplest way to convert C# method to asynchronous call Page/Web Method or jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asynchronous

I have a C# method from a web form that I want to call asynchronously with with either a Page Method, Web Method or possibly jQuery to avoid postback to the server. The method calls other methods and rebuilds a treeview and performs validation and sets some other values as well. Below is an example of the code.

What would be the simpleset way to do this? 
Any code samples provided would be greatly appreciated if possible. No update Panels..

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{


        if (ValidateSelection() == true)
        {
            int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(grdGetProducts.SelectedValue.ToString());


            if (Convert.ToInt32(ddBetTypeID.SelectedItem.Value) != 2)
            {
                SubmitProduct(Convert.ToInt32(ddProductTypeID.SelectedItem.Value), currentWeek, Convert.ToInt32(ddProductID.SelectedItem.Value), Convert.ToInt32(ddValue.SelectedItem.Value), Convert.ToInt32(ddCost.SelectedItem.Value), ProductID);
            }


            if (Convert.ToInt32(ddProductTypeID.SelectedItem.Value) == 2)
            {

                int price;
                price= 1;
                //if 1 open side then part 2
                if (txtProductID.Text != "0" && txt2ProductID.Text == "0")
                {
                    price= 2;

                }


            if (ProductID > 2)
            {
                BuildTree(currentTime, Convert.ToInt32(ddProductID.SelectedItem.Value), currentProduct);

            }




        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an update panel you are certainly going to need a lot of client side javascript.

I do things like this with dynamic tables all the time and the first thing I did was isolate my data and my display. You should start by doing the same.

Figure out what data is being validated and how you can gather it on the client to be sent to a web method. Then you need to write client scripts to do this gathering and posting. After you post with the client script, in the callback of the ajax call, you would then need to do the rendering on the page. Without an update panel this is all on you.

The issue you have without using an update panel is that you are going to have to recreate the treeview structure or manipulate it on the client side. This means replacing all the elements and their event handlers. This can be a very daunting task for the more complicated ASP controls.

What the server would need to send back for rendering would be all of the data the tree needs. It is on you to figure out what that is though.

I have dynamically rendered gridviews before because it is nice to use them to create complex styles. Then it is just a matter of creating rows with the script on the client, based on the data I get from the server; I imagine you can do something similar to this with a treeview.

I have learned a lot about jQuery, ajax and ASP.NET interactions by reading [encosia.com](http://encosia.com). That individual is a wonderful resource.

- [Things to avoid using jQuery AJAX and ASP.NET](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)
- [Mistakes: manual JSON serialization](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/)
- [Using jQuery to directly call asp.net page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)
- [Update Panels are Dangerous](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)

Comment: Powlan, thank you for sharing your thoughts and experiences on this. Makes sense.

Comment: It seems like a lot but once you have it done, there is a lot of code you can reuse. Good luck.